# Many to Many relationship between dimensions in a DW - The better modeling?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, modeling

I have this situation in front of me and I would like to ask for your opinion about modeling :

- An event can have several invited companies ( Accounts )
- A company ( Account) can of course attend several events
- An event has a start time and an end time and a total cost

As you can see there's a Many to Many relationship ( Dim_Event ) and ( Dim_Accounts )
My question is how to model this in a DW .

What I have done:
Inserting a "Table Bridge" called EVENT_GUEST_BRIDGE in which I put a key to Dim_Event and another key to Dim_Accounts .
It's like a * - * table generated when defining a Many to Many relationship between two entities .

Fact_EVENT the table is linked to the Dim_Event and is doubly linked to the dimension of time since an event has a start date and an end date.

[image]

To have for eg the countries from which companies participating in an Event I have to Write :

```
SELECT [FK_EVENT]
,[FK_DEBUT_EVENT]
,[FK_FIN_EVENT]
,[TotalPriceByEvent]
,C.Country
FROM [DW_CRM].[dbo].[Fact_MARKETING_EVENT] A 
inner join [DW_CRM].[dbo].[EVENT_GUEST_ACCOUNT_BRIDGE] B on (A.FK_EVENT = B.FK_Event_ID)
inner join [DW_CRM].[dbo].[Dim_Accounts] C on (B.FK_Account_ID = C.Accounts_TechKey)
```

Would it be better if I have for example opt for a purely star design ?
something like that :

[image]

I wish I knew the + and - of each design!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what you're looking to model. The first models each *event* as a fact, whereas the other will model each *attendance* or *invitation* as a fact. What you have to ask yourself is how this will affect what you measure. It also depends strongly on what measurable data you have. I'm not sure what `TotalPriceByEvent` contains or if you have another measure that you can use, but probably the best piece of advice I can give is to always, where feasible, use the finest grain of data you have available.

If you have, for example, entry fees per company, go with the *invitation* grain - you can likely produce calculated measures simulating the snowflake, but going the other way is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opinion the second option is the best design, this based on experience and also on theorical concepts given by the dimensional modeling authors and experts(i recommend reading their book: the data warehouse toolkit by kimball).

The second approach is  cleaner, gives better understanding and its closer to what the business people would understand if you give them the diagram. One of the design patterns kimball gives is to break many to many relationshipts on the fact table, and thats what your second design does, also your queries will be cleaner, and probably with best performance.